# Display last numbers of REDIRECTED link

Tags: php

How i can display the last numbers of a redirected url in php?

with redirected, i mean something like this

```
$nick=$_GET['nickname'];
$url='http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/' . $nick . '';
```

For example, if the url is script.php?nickname=Skyleter, will be http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/Skyleter, the problem here is it redirects to http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/Skyleter.17529827, (try yourself) so i want to display the numbers of the redirected url.

Wich, for me is 17529827

Is this possible?

**Please dont say "the last 8 digits" like $variable = substr($url, -8); , so every nick has different ID.**

Also ill like to display a custom error when input is value. [script.php and not script.php?nick=nick]

It displays "undefinex index" by default.

Thanks!

Comment: What's in the html form?

Comment: <form action="avatar1.php" method="get" name="form">
     <input type="number" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname" />
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
      </form>´

Comment: Alright check my answer.

Comment: Thank you, you solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this url will redirect you, you will need to use curl to get the next one.

This will work:

```
<?php
$nick='Skyleter'; //$_GET['nickname'];
$url='http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/' . $nick;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
 $l = trim($r[1]);

$user_id = end((explode('.', $l)));
echo $user_id;
?>
```

It explodes the string at the last dot `(.)`, which is what comes right before the ID.

Comment: Thank you a **TON**, it worked fine! :D U helped me a ton i searched this for hours

Answer (score 2):

If it's always going to be numbers, you could use filter_var to easily pull them out.

```
$url = 'http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/Skyleter.17529827';
$id = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

echo $id; // 17529827
```

If the nickname contains numbers though, this won't work. If the format stays that way (always ending with a dot and a set of numbers), then I guess you could use pathinfo and read that as the extension of your path.

```
$urlParts = pathinfo('http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/Skyleter1111.17529827');
echo $urlParts['extension'];
```

Comment: What if the nickname contains numbers? And how are you getting the id?

Comment: Hmm, then this wouldn't work for you since the function would include those numbers as well.

Comment: See my edit for another method of extracting these numbers

Comment: Thanks! but as i said ill like  ['http://es.cheese.formice.com/mouse/' . $nick . '';] ---- $nick=$_GET['nickname']; so Phiter Fernandes script worked for me. Thanks anyways `[again] because im pretty sure ill need it in the future! :)